# “Grouping” dictionary by key value pair using linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, group-by

“Grouping” dictionary by key value pair using linq c#.I did't get anything.How to do in linq.1 how do i convert Dictionary of key value pair of string and string using linq and c#.I did't get anything.How to do in linq.

```
{
  Namevalue" : 2,

   "hotellist" :
    [
        {
            "id" : 1288,   
            "name" : "nwealth",
            "street" : "500 Commonwealth Avenue",
            "city" : "Boston",
            "postal_code" : "02215",

            "room_types"  :
                {
                    "Room 1" :
                        {
                            "url" : "google-",
                            "desc" : "dddfddd."
                        },
                   "Room 2" :
                        {
                            "url" : "yahoo-",
                            "desc" : "dddfddd."
                        }
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

Linq query:

```
      var InventoryData = res.GroupBy(x => new
            {
                x.Id,
                x.Name,
                x.Address,
                x.City               
            },
                (Key, group) => new
            {
                HotelId = Key.Id,
                groups = group.ToList()
            }).ToList().ForEach(r =>
                {
                    room = r.groups.ForEach(x =>
                         (Key, group) => new Hotelroomtypes
                         {
                             roomname = Key.HotelRoomTypeDesc,
                             RoomType = group.ToList()
                         });                     
                });

         }
```

I did't get anything.How to do in linq.

Comment: Seems to be your first question here. Please take some time to read the help center on how to ask questions. It'll help you. The better your question the better the answers you may expect. The first point to clear up would be: where's the dictionary you mention in the title? `res` doesn't seem to be a dictionary. Second point: show the source data and the result you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of `ForEach` method is `public void ForEach(Action<T> action)`[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx). So you cannot store result in variable `InventoryData`. And as action method in `ForEach` method you set value into `room` variable but this value is rewrote to last value for each element of collection.

I don't know what do you want to do but you can change `ForEach` to `Select` method and instead of setting `room` variable return it.